# Automating App Engine Deployments with Cloud Build failed with error

Tags: django, repository, gcloud

Now I am setting up "Automating App Engine Deployments with Cloud Build" at GCP and stuck at final step of [Quickstarts](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart-triggering-builds-with-source-repositories).
There is error message when I checked "Build history" after `git push origin master`. And it is hard for me to understand what the message means.

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) There is a cloudbuild.yaml in the current
>   directory, and the runtime field in /workspace/app.yaml is currently
>   set to [runtime: python]. To use your cloudbuild.yaml to build a
>   custom runtime, set the runtime field to [runtime: custom]. To
>   continue using the [python] runtime, please remove the cloudbuild.yaml
>   from this directory.

Please refer to following codes in the source directory,

app.yaml

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT acct.wsgi

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy"]
timeout: "1600s"
```